# Why didn't Zelena enact her other plans in Once Upon a Time?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

Might be a dumb question possibly answered by

> Zelena's being Marian

being a late addition to the story but:

> Zelena wanted to go back to the past to change stuff like never being abandoned or wiping Regina from existence.
>
>  After Rumple tried to kill her, she was able to go back to the past

Soooooo why didn't she do the things she was supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

If you remember the episode [Kansas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kansas_(Once_Upon_a_Time)),

> Zelena, after being defeated and imprisoned, was *killed* by Rumplestiltskin and her lingering life essence was the last ingredient needed to open the time portal. The time portal opens and sucks Emma, Hook, and Zelena into the Enchanted Forest past.

At this point, he/she is down and almost out, and just wants revenge. She is no match for the Evil Queen of this time and just capitalizes on the opportunity that Emma wanted to save Marian and take her to present day Storybrooke. So,

> she kills Marian and steals her identity with the Six-Leaf clover. This actually worked wonderfully for her, because she completely destroyed Regina's happy ending, for a little while anyway.

Comment: Thanks Arm0geddon. 1 'was killed by' --> How do we know this? 2 'lingering life essence was the last ingredient needed to open the time portal' --> was it? 3 'down and almost out, and just wants revenge' --> How do we know this?

Comment: @BCLC I believe if you just watch the episode KANSAS, all your questions will be answered.